# Debugging cdb with -c always stops at break instruction exception

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have compiled Firefox and has a JS script that will cause the program to crash.

The only problem I am having using CDB is passing options to the `-c` command-line option.

Here is my sample session:

`cdb js.exe hello.js -c ".dump /ma /o c:\debug\debug.dmp;q"`

Instead, I am getting

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: js.exe test.js -c ".dump /ma /o c:\debug\debug.dmp;q"
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\WINDOWS\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download
/symbols
Executable search path is:
ModLoad: 00000000`00140000 00000000`00434000   js.exe
ModLoad: 00000000`77a80000 00000000`77c2b000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`77c60000 00000000`77de0000   ntdll32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`75610000 00000000`7564f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`751e0000 00000000`7523c000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`75790000 00000000`75798000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
(a58.b0c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00000000`77b31220 cc              int     3
0:000>
```

I want to make a minidump by launching this the executable and the script. Is there a problem with this kind of approach?

Ultimately, I am trying to use this line I construct:  `-c "bp main; lines; g; .dump c:/debug/debug.dmp; q"`

No matter what I put into the command, the same "Welcome" shows up. I suspect this means the executable is not launched? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
-g ignores initial breakpoint in debuggee
```